# Insert data to arraylist java as odd and even position

Tags: java

```
    // size data1 and data2 is different or same
    List<String> data1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
    List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();

    data1.add("home1");
    data1.add("home2");
    data2.add("car1");
    data2.add("car2");
    data2.add("car3");  

    // this list combine data1 and data2 but data1 in odd index position and data2 in even position
    List<String> combine = new ArrayList<>();
    int dataSize = data1.size() + data2.size();
    for (int i = 1; i< dataSize; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            if (!data1.isEmpty()) {
                combine.add(data1.get(0));
                combine.remove(0);
            }
        } else {
            if (!data2.isEmpty()) {
                combine.add(data2.get(0));
                combine.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
// i want to get data as bellow
    // combine.get(0) => home1
    // combine.get(1) => car1
    // combine.get(2) => home2
    // combine.get(3) => car2
    // combine.get(0) => car3
```

how i can insert data to combine list as odd and even position from data1 and data2. This code is not work beacause data size data1 and data2 sometimes is different.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working about it _specifically_?

Comment: and what does your question have to do with Spring Boot?

Comment: sorry i have edit question. please help me

Comment: Could you add some sample data (input & expected output)? I'm assuming you want to just kind of "weave" the array lists together, but I'm confused by the code and thinking maybe I'm not correct.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if the two lists have different lengths?

Comment: example i have 2 data1 and 3 data2. i loop 5, so data2 index 2 is not yet insert.

Comment: If you want to only insert until data2 index 1, can you like get the smaller length, which is 2, and iterate int i like 2 times, and get one from data1, another one from data2, and append to the third list, and that\`s it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main issues, firstly you use `combine.add(data1.get(0));` and `combine.add(data2.get(0));` which will only ever add the first element of each list to the combine array. And the second issue is that after inserting an element you immediatly remove it again `combine.remove(0);`.

Consider the following solution which simply inserts the elements in order (and also makes sure we don't get an out of bounds error):

```
List<String> data1 = Arrays.asList("zero", "two", "four", "six");
List<String> data2 = Arrays.asList("one", "three", "five", "seven");

int longest = data1.size() > data2.size() ? data1.size() : data2.size();

List<String> combine = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
    //Add each item in order
    if (data1.size() > i) {
        combine.add(data1.get(i));
    }
    if (data2.size() > i) {
        combine.add(data2.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(combine.toString());
```

And the output is as expected in alternating order:

```
[zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven]
```

Comment: `longest` can be simplified with `Math.max()`.

Comment: Absolutely, I will leave it expanded as is so that OP can follow the flow. Your answer already covers the most ideal solution if OP wants it condensed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to track even and odd indexes. Just copy one item from each non-empty list until you're out of items. If you were trying to clear the source lists as you merge them, you don't even need an index:

```
while (!data1.isEmpty() || !data2.isEmpty()) {
    if (!data1.isEmpty()) combine.add(data1.remove(0));
    if (!data2.isEmpty()) combine.add(data2.remove(0));
}
```

You can also use an iterator (optionally calling `remove()` after `next()`):

```
Iterator<String> iter1 = data1.iterator();
Iterator<String> iter2 = data2.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext() || iter2.hasNext()) {
    if (iter1.hasNext()) combine.add(iter1.next());
    if (iter2.hasNext()) combine.add(iter2.next());
}
```